# How do I create multiple dataframes from a loop based on two existing dataframes and matching creteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I think the below code might make my question easier to understand. But I'll try explain what I want to do anyway.

I have two dataframes, There is one column common to each. I want the rows from df2 that match based on the values in df1's col 1 to be put in a separate dataframe and loop through df2 until I have new dataframes for each of the criteria in df1's col1.

```
Dataframes

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', '1'], ['p', '3']],
                   columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['t','a', '1'], ['q','a', '2'], ['x','p', '3']],
                   columns=['col 1', 'col 2', 'col 3'])


for strategy in df2:
if df2[df2['col 2']] == df1[df1['col 1']]:
        df = df2[df2['col 2']] == df1[df1['strategy']]
        df.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Sheet_name_1')
```

After that, I want to use each new dataframe in the loop and perform a function on it and then export that new dataframe to excel. But for the time being lets focus on the first problem.

Comment: Your source code isn't syntactically correct python or pandas code. Can you provide the expected resulting dataframe?

Comment: Hi mikksu, I've added a better example as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample is unclear about what should contain each sheet in the output
Excel file.

So I took another approach to generate DataFrames for each sheet:
For each value in *col 2* column in *df2* (I named it *vv*):

- generate a (temporary) DataFrame - rows from *df1* with *col 1*
  equal to *vv*,
- save it as a sheet with the name taken form *vv*.

To write an Excel file with multiple sheets, you have to:

- definie an *ExcelWriter* object, connected to the output file
  (before the loop),
- call *to_excel*, passing the above object and the sheet name
  (in the loop),
- close the Excel writer (after the loop).

The code to do it is:

```
exw = pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx')
for vv in df2['col 2'].unique():
    df1.query('`col 1` == @vv').to_excel(exw, vv)
exw.save()
```

Note how concise it this code:

- *df1.query('`col 1` == @vv')* - generates the output DataFrame
  (from *df1*),
- *to_excel(exw, vv)* - writes it to the output file (as a separate sheet).

Now you have to:

- define what should be the content of each sheet,
- adjust my code accordingly.

Comment: Hi Valdi_Bo. Yes, apologies, first time posting. My code wasn't very clear and I couldn't use my exact code from work so I posted the above on the fly. I've added the answer I'm working with now, that a colleague provided below. Its a better example too.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution provided to me by a colleague in work. A big thank you to him.

So, we have two dataframes, with a common columns being Strategy and Style in both (indices and funds).
We set the index to the Strategy column values in the indices dataframe.
We then create a dictionary of dataframes from the funds dataframe. Each of these is based on the Style value.
Now we create an example function that we can run.
And finally we create a function that selects each of the new dataframes and takes the index assigned to each fund and passes them to our new function and gives us our final set of dataframes. At this point we would export each to excel individually per sheet (I'm still working on this part)

```
import pandas as pd

indices = pd.DataFrame([['Volatility', 'SPX Index'], ['Multistrategy', 'SXXP Index'], ['Real Estate', 'IBEX Index']],
                   columns=['Strategy', 'Ticker'])

indices = indices.set_index('Strategy') # i would have the strategy as index to help with mapping later

funds = pd.DataFrame([['MABAX US Equity','Real Estate', 'name1'], ['SPY US Equity','Real Estate', 'name2'],
                      ['AAPL US Equity','Volatility', 'name3']],
                   columns=['Ticker', 'Style', 'Name'])


strategies = indices.index.values

data_frames = {strategy:funds[funds['Style']==strategy] for strategy in strategies}
#this gives you a dictionary of dataframes so you can get funds of volatility with
# something like: data_frames['Volatility']

def my_function(fund_df,parameter,index_ticker):
    #this is your function and it takes the fund df of each
    #strategy and also the index ticker of each strategy
    print(fund_df)
    print(index_ticker)
    return

#you could run the function for each dataframe and each index by using something like:

for strategy in strategies:
    index_ticker = indices.loc[strategy,'Ticker']
    fund_df = data_frames[strategy]
    my_function(fund_df,'M',index_ticker)
```